# "Please use English" or "Please use the English language"?

Tags: word-usage

We are having an argument, about the correctness of saying "Please use English".

- A: Is it correct?
- B: Is "Please use the English language" more correct?
- C: Is the "Please use English" acceptable as a way to shorten the expression? (it is for a title, so space is scarce)

One side argues that "Please use English" would incite people to for instance take British persons and make them cook Fish & Chips.

Comment: I'd not *use* 'use'. Rather *speak/write/type* **in** English. No ambiguity that way!

Comment: @MaulikV I wrote the question that way, but it actually includes "English Usage" vs. "English Language Usage", for which your tip unfortunately does not work.

Comment: It makes no difference whether you say "Pease use English/the English language. In the sentence English means English Language, not English people. The English refer to the people of Britain.

Comment: @Khan: Thanks for the explanation! Would you mind making your comment an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Please use English**, **Please use the English language** and **In English please** are all equivalent in meaning.

Depending on usage, **English** implies the language, not the people, so, **Please use English** would suffice. **The English** are the people:

> Fish and chips is a favourite of **the English**, as well as the Welsh and the Scots.

**Please use the English language** is correct, but bulky, as if spoken by or spoken to a non-native English speaker.